# Can't detect WIFI

Tags: wireless, dual-boot, internet

I'm relatively new to Ubuntu and just dual booted 12.04 LTS with Windows 8.1
I can connect to WIFI with Windows; however, it doesn't allow me to with Ubuntu. It doesn't detect any wireless networks even when manually entered. It does connect via direct connection by ethernet cable. Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: post the output of `sudo rfkill list`

Answer (score 0):

First Check rfkill list commands. it shows wireless. Then Check your Additional Drivers in system settings whether it contains the Broadcomm STA wirless driver or not. If it is not and also if it have but you can't activate the driver in that time. you have to do this steps

First we have to remove the bcmwl kernel source
    sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source

Then again install
    sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source